# RegEx how to get domain from domain\username

Tags: .net, regex, nintex-workflow

RegEx to get domain from domain\username. I tried this but it returns the entire string.

```
/^(.*?)\.\\/
```

What am I doing incorrectly? the end result should be domain

Comment: Please show the code you're using to extract the string.

Comment: you're much likely to get good help if you also post your code and some input/expected output examples

Answer (score 5):

Regex is quite the large hammer for such a tiny nail. Just use `IndexOf`.

```
string domain = str.SubString(0, str.IndexOf('\\'));
```

Comment: I did not see IndexOf option in nintex workflow. I only takes .net compatible expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using regular expressions then what you are doing wrong is that you are are not escaping the \ (I'm also not sure why the . is there) Try

```
/^(.*?)\\.*$/
```

However for such a simple problem you would be better served just using .IndexOf to find the \ and then .Substring to return everything before it.

Comment: that code gives me the entire string. I tried this and it gives me domain\ but i dont need the trailing \ at the end. (?<=\\).*$

Answer (score 0):

^(.*?)\\

Will give you domain\

^.[^\\]*

Will give you domain

[^x] gives you everything but x
and \ has to be escaped likeso \\.